# Not able to deploy war in JBoss AS 7 through Eclipse luna.

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss7.x, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse luna with Jboss tools 4.2.0.Beta2 and JbossAS 7.1.1.

I am deployed my application from eclipse and started Jboss.
Then i'm getting a problem that deployment starts completes the deployment and again re deploy the application.
Its happening for more than 2 times and undeploys.

I am not able to deploy my application.

Please share the resolution for the above problem.

Comment: Try deploying the app manually. Copy the `war` file to JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/ and start the jboss from JBOSS_HOME/bin with `./standalone.sh`.

Comment: yes i can have done and its working. But i have to debug my application So, i need to deploy my web application from eclipse.

Comment: I am not sure why it is undeployed. But you can run your server in debug mode and do Remote debugging.

Is there anything in server logs?

Comment: Exactly, no need to deploy the app just to have the jboss running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

On your `standalone.xml` edit `deployment-scanner` with `enabled="true"` and `auto-deploy-exploded="true"`

```
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-enabled="true" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="true" deployment-timeout="1200" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
```